# Aptana HTML formatter bug

Tags: aptana

It seems that aptana HTML formatter doesn't understant when I have css directly in html source, with !important keyword.

exemple :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<styl type="text/css">
#thisisatest {
background: red !important;
}
</styl>
</html>
```

I use aptana 3 as a plugin for eclipse.
thanks,
trey

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue to Studio 3.0.3: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2920.  It has been fixed in the latest nightly build that you could update to (http://www.aptana.com/r/apupdate), or wait for the upcoming 3.0.4 release.